# ASP.NET MVC 5 consumiendo api

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Estoy desarrollando una plataforma nueva la cual consume data desde una api de la SBIF, pero el JSON con la data que me devuelve viene asi

```
{
    "Dolares":
    [
        {
            "Valor": "603,31",
            "Fecha": "2018-04-27"
        {
    ]
}
```

Para consumirla uso httpClient y me arroja un error de "deserialize" eh ocupado varias tecnicas que encontre en por aca pero ninguna me funciona. El error que me retorna la view es este.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DetamaticWeb.Models.DolarViewModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'Dolares', line 2, position 12.

Alguien seria tan amable para que me indicara como debería consumir esta api por favor?

Controller

```
string Baseurl = "http://api.sbif.cl/";
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            List<DolarViewModel> EmpInfo = new List<DolarViewModel>();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format  
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api");

                //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                    var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                    EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DolarViewModel>>(EmpResponse);

                }
                //returning the employee list to view  
                return View(EmpInfo);
            }
        }
```

Model

```
public class DolarViewModel
{
    public string Valor { get; set; }
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Añade el código que estas utilizando para ver que error estas cometiendo y poder ayudarte.

Comment: ahí actualice la pregunta con el código del controller que esta consumiendo la data.

Comment: Puedes mostrar la clase DolarViewModel, pero creo que he visto tu error. Estas indicando que se va a devolver una lista de la clase DolarViewModel, pero viendo tu json se devuelve un objeto no una lista, dentro de este objeto si que te devuelve una lista de valores.

Comment: ahi actualice la pregunta con el codigo del Model. Entonces como debería recuperarla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que veo es que el modelo es este:

```
Public Class DolarViewModel{
    public List<ListaValoresDolarViewModel> Dolares {get; set;}
}

Public Class ListaValoresDolarViewModel{
    public string Valor { get; set; }
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
}
```

Y para recuperar esos datos sería:

```
EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DolarViewModel>(EmpResponse);
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias, pero ahora me aparece un error en la linea que me enviaste para recuperar la data. El error que me indica visual studio es este:

> No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo 'Models.DolarViewModel' en 'System.Collection.Generic.List<Models.DolarViewModel>'

Comment: Me olvide comentarte que tienes que cambiar el tipo de EmpInfo a DolarViewModel  porque ahora mismo es una lista. Si te sirve la respuesta marcala como tal.

Comment: Gracias ! me sirvió un montón, ahí quedo marcada.

Comment: Hola, sabes que eh estado teniendo problemas para recuperar la data desde la vista. La estoy recuperando como una lista de ListaValoresDolarViewModel pero no puedo.

Comment: Si tienes problemas puedes crear otra pregunta con el problema para poder ayudarte, ya que en principio esta pregunta esta resuelta.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes parsear a un [dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) y utilizarlo directamente a las propiedades o recorrerlas. Es muy util cuando accesamos a APIs y no tenemos que generar un modelo para eso en nuestra capa de entidades. Tomalo como otra alternativa "mas liviana"

Ejemplo con dynamic:

```
var jsonData = "{\"Dolares\":[{\"Valor\": \"603,31\",\"Fecha\": \"2018-04-27\"}]}";
        dynamic demo = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonData);

        Console.WriteLine(demo.Dolares[0].Valor);
        Console.WriteLine(demo.Dolares[0].Fecha);

        foreach (var item in demo.Dolares)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Valor);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Fecha);
        }
```

Que es lo mismo que tener (dependiendo de tu arquitectura y que es lo que hagas con el viewModel que armas) que este codigo que tiene el modelo "predefinido"

```
 DolarViewModel demo2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DolarViewModel>(jsonData);
        Console.WriteLine(demo2.Dolares[0].Valor);
        Console.WriteLine(demo2.Dolares[0].Fecha);

        foreach (var item in demo2.Dolares)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Valor);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Fecha);
        }
```

Suponiendo que el DolarViewModel es igual a

```
 public class DolarViewModel
{
    public List<ListaValoresDolarViewModel> Dolares { get; set; }
}

public class ListaValoresDolarViewModel
{
    public string Valor { get; set; }
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
}
```

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Uso de tipo dinámico (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia